# html/js/jquery detect unfakeable cell phone location

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, sms

There are many apps out there which fake the geo location of a cell phone.
Is there a way to detect unfakeable cell phone location / geo location using web stuff like html, javascript, jquery etc. or native cell phone stuff like SMS?

Comment: You would need to define `unfakeable` first

Answer (score 1):

You can trace their IP address https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo.

Please note that this, even their IP, can be spoofed - albeit it would be somewhat more difficult. There is currently no "full-proof" way to trace someones location. If there were - I'm sure the NSA would be all over it by now. But for common use cases (99%) of the time. Just trust the user or confirm their general location with an IP trace and your fine.